# Clustering SQL VMs

Tags: hyper-v, sql

In our environment, we have physical servers running Server 2003 and SQL 2005 that are clustered with iSCSI storage disks for the data, logs, and backup disks. 
We would like to move these to VMs on a Hyper-V cluster. Based on some initial research that I've done, I've come up with these steps to accomplish this:

1. Fail over all resources to node 1.
2. Perform a P2V using SCVMM on node 2.
3. Shut down the physical machine for node 2 and turn on the VM.
4. Fail over all resources to node 2.
5. Perform a P2V using SCVMM on node 1.
6. Shut down the physical machine for node 1 and turn on the VM.
7. Balance the cluster.

Since we would do a P2V on a physical machine, the iSCSI initiator should operate on the VM just as it does on the physical machine, assuming the IP addresses are the same, so the iSCSI disks should show up. Is this the recommended method for accomplishing this? Is there an easier way? Would this method be supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done a migration like that, it seems like it should work, however I'd highly reccomend building the vm cluster from scratch if you can afford a little downtime when the iscsi resourse gets moved.  After you P2V the machine there is usually cruft left over that affects the vm performance and by the time you factor in the time you'll spend cleaning up the VM you'll find you could have just built a new machine.

Answer (score 0):

We haven't had any success with P2V.  While we are using netware, which I believe isn't currently supported.  It is nice to be forced to rebuild sometimes.  (In our case, especially so, not that sles10 oes is any better :( ).  Microsoft Hyper-V P2V should work seamlessly with Msoft servers.  Good luck, let us know how it goes.